# TailwindCSS | how to set correct color inside config file to be rendered as RGB/RGBA

Tags: tailwind-css

Tailwind provides good option to get value from config inside another config object

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: 'red'
    },
    extend: {
      colors: theme => ({
        secondary: theme('colors.primary') // will be red 
      })
    }
  }
}
```

But this doesn't work when I want to create classes using RGBA. I want to create something like

```
module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      primary: 'red'
    },
    extend: {
      boxShadow: theme => ({
        extra: "0 0 999px rgba(theme('colors.primary'), .25))"
      }),
    }
  }
}
```

This will render `0 0 999px rgba(red, .25)` which is not correct CSS value - you need to pass `red` as `255, 0, 0`. But I want to use `colors.primary` as it was defined in my config

I know Tailwind has it's own build utils for converting colors like `asRgba`, `withAlphaVariable`. For example, when you use `text-white` Tailwind renders it as `color: rgba(255,255,255,var(--tw-text-opacity));`. But how can I use it?

So basically how can I achieve this - pass color key from my config into another property and get rendered it as RGB/RGBA?

**Update:** I want third square (TW) to work as others

[DEMO](https://play.tailwindcss.com/mAN6dX7Cw8?file=config)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your idea was wrong, because tailwind `colors` is defined with HEX number, but you trying to use it into RGBA type, so I think you need to convert firstly if you want to make your way.
Anyway let us know your success :)

check this [doc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5623838/rgb-to-hex-and-hex-to-rgb)

Comment: No unfortunatelly this didn't work even in your playground, `shadow-extra` class does nothing. If I'll pass rgb value instead it will do the job but the questions is how to avoid that and use colors keys of your config

Comment: That's exactly the point of my question. I checked this link before. Updated the question with demo maybe it will help. Thanks)

Answer (score 0):

I was having a problem because i had a dynamic hex color that i wanted to add an opacity modifier to so i used a simple js function to convert hex to rgb

```
const hexToRgb = (hexColor) => {
  let r, g, b;
  console.log(hexColor);
  r = parseInt(hexColor.slice(0, 2), 16);
  g = parseInt(hexColor.slice(2, 4), 16);
  b = parseInt(hexColor.slice(4, 6), 16);
  return `${r} ${g} ${b}`;
};
```

assign them to css variables using JS

```
 document.documentElement.style.setProperty(
    "--backend-issue-label-color",
    hexToRgb(BackendIssueLabelColor),
  );
```

and in tailwind.config.js

```
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        backend: {
          DEFAULT: "rgb( var(--backend-issue-label-color) / var(--bg-opacity) )",
          foreground: "rgb( var(--backend-issue-label-color) / var(--text-opacity) )",
          border: "rgb( var(--backend-issue-label-color) / var(--border-opacity) )",
        },
    }
    }
```

then set the opacity modifiers using css variables but hardcoded into index.css

```
@layer base  {
    :root.dark {
        --bg-opacity:0.6;
        --text-opacity:0.9;
        --border-opacity:1;
    }
    :root  {
        --bg-opacity:0.3;
        --text-opacity:0.1;
        --border-opacity:0.6;
    }
}
```